# Trying to fetch username from the session in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch username/fullname from the current session in php. I am getting no result. Any solution from the community will be appreciated.

```
<?php
$username=$_SESSION['login'];
$sql = "SELECT FullName FROM USERS WHERE kUsername=:username ";
$query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query-> bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
    foreach($results as $result)
    {?>

<?php }}?>
<?php print htmlentities($result->FullName); ?>
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php echo htmlentities($result->FullName);?></label>
```

Comment: you dont call session_start before() , there for there is no $_SESSION variable at all

Comment: echo $sql; and run  this sql query in you db and see what hapen? i think your variable $username has no value

Comment: session_start(); was added in the starting.

Comment: @rowmoin exactly $username has no value

Comment: Got the solution  $username=$_SESSION['alogin']; . I missed 'a'

Comment: I knew it so, when you geating this type of issue you should debug step by step then you will be find your problem

Comment: Thanks @rowmoin I will definitely keep in mind.

Comment: wellcome :)  @SabhaySardana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this solution based on the comments above.

First need to make sure you call `session_start` before trying to use the `$_SESSION` variable.

Then make sure `$username = $_SESSION['login'];` is the value you want to lookup. Based on your comment, it looks like it should be `$username=$_SESSION['alogin'];`